# Wrong Derived Class Methods Execution on Event?

Tags: c#, events, inheritance, custom-event

```
public Class A
{

   public A()
   {
     someotherclass.someevent += new EventHandler(HandleEvent);
   }

   private void HandleEvent(object sender,CustomEventArgs e) 
   {
      if(e.Name == "Type1")
           Method1();
      else if(e.Name == "Type2")
           Method2();
   }

   protected virtual void Method1(){}
   protected virtual void Method2(){}
}

public class B: A
{
   public B()
   { /*Something*/}

   protected override void Method1(){/*some logic*/}
   protected override void Method2(){/*some other logic*/}
}

public class C: A
{
   public C()
   { /*Something*/}

   protected override void Method1(){/*some logic*/}
   protected override void Method2(){/*some other logic*/}
}

public class Main
{
    private A;

    public Main(){/*Something*/}

    private void StartB()
    {
       A = new B();
    } 

    private void StartC()
    {
       A = new C();
    } 
}
```

Now, what happens is, after I go through a cycle in which both the methods **StartB**(called first) and **StartC**(called second) are called, when the **someevent** is triggered, the code tries to execute the Method in **Class B**(*and later Class C, I hope. I could not get there since it errors out when it calls method in Class B*), instead which I want it to call only the method in **Class C**.

I think that, since the event is subscribed at constructor, Class B methods are still getting fired since it is subscribed initially on the call of StartB.

**Question:**
I want only the methods of the class that is instantiated the latest should be executed.

For Example: if **StartB** and **StartC** are called in order, when **someevent** is triggered the Methods in **Class C** should only get executed. Same Vice-Versa. How to do that?

I know am doing something terribly wrong. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What's the problem? What you have said is correct, but you have not asked any question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't unsubscribing from the event from your first instance so it will be called.  If you don't want it to be called you need to unsubscribe.  You *could* do something like this

```
class A
{

private static EventHandler lastHandler;

public A()
{
    //warning, not thread safe
    if(lastHandler != null)
    {
        someotherclass.someevent -= lastHandler;
    }
    lastHandler = new EventHandler(HandleEvent);
    someotherclass.someevent += lastHandler;
}
```

but it seems pretty hacky.  You are probably better off implementing a method (e.g. `IDisposable`) to clean up your last instance before a creating a new one.

Comment: Thanks Yaur. I implemented the IDisposable Interface and unsubscribed to the event in the Dispose method before creating new instance. That worked!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you are saying the methods on B are being called after startC is called and you don't wish this to happen?

I'm guessing your issue is that someotherclass is a static class, or an instance is somehow being shared between all the created B's and C's - in which case you need to unregister the old event handler from someotherclass.someevent when you create the new class. If you don't unregister the handler then the someotherclass object will have a reference to the B or C object that registered with it, so even though you are overwriting the reference in the main class the object is still kept alive by the reference in the event and is still being called when the event is triggered.